# Question regarding Pointwise and Uniform Convergence

Tags: uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x) = x^n + \frac{e^2x}{n^2}$. As $n \to \infty$, $f_n$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ on $[0,1]$.

(i) What is $f$?

(ii) Is this convergence uniform?

(iii) Let $p$ be fixed (but arbitrary) with $0 < p < 1$. Show that $f_n \to f$ on $[0,p)$.

(iv) Is the convergence uniform on $[0,p)$?

Comment: what have you tried ? at least the pointwise convergence should not be a problem

Comment: My answer for (i) f = 0 for 0<=x<1 and f=1+e^2 as x=1. Is it right?

Comment: no, what is the limit of $\frac{e^2}{n^2}$ as $n\to\infty$ ?

Comment: for that limit is 0...

Comment: oh, i get limit of 1^n + e^2/n^2 as n -> infinity is 1 (when x=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to the function $f$ defined by
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}\\
0\quad\text{if}\ 0\leq x<1 \\
1\quad\text{if}\ x=1\end{array}\right.$$
and since $f$ isn't continuous whereas $f_n$ are continuous then the convergence isn't uniform.

On the interval $[0,p)$ the limit function is $f\equiv 0$ and we have
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=x^n+\frac{e^2x}{n^2}\leq p^n+\frac{e^2p}{n^2}\to 0\quad \forall x\in[0,p)$$
so the sequence is uniformly convergent to $f$ on $[0,p)$.